# UIButton Not Working After Updated to Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uibutton

After I updated to Xcode 8.3 the following code is not working in Xcode Playgrounds. Before on Xcode 8.2.1, I was able to click on the button and the action would follow, but now nothing is happening when I click the button.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 550, height: 575))
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 550, height: 575))
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
view.presentScene(scene)

class Responder: NSObject {
    @objc func nextScene() {
        print("Next button pressed!")
    }
}
let responder = Responder()

let nextButton = UIButton(type: .system)
nextButton.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 557.5, width: 40, height: 15)
nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
nextButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 17)
nextButton.tintColor = .black
nextButton.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responder.nextScene), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(nextButton)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

EDIT: I updated my code so that it includes PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view and the code for setting up the view and scene.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set a live view for the playground in your code. Normally, a playground will execute the code and stop - it does not wait for input or events etc, unless you explicitly specify it should.

You should add the following line at the end of the playground to specify that `canvas` is a live view - provided it is, I can't know since you have not provided the implementation for `canvas`.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = canvas
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that part when I copied the code over from my project. I edited by question and added that code as well as the code used to create my view and scene.